# mv command for many nonexistent files, does it wear off the destination disk at all?

Tags: hard-disk, performance, mv, ssd, ramdisk

I am trying to continuously move many files (~ 10 000 each minute) from /ramdisk to normal /ssd , but not all files are there.

When the `mv /ramdisk/file55 /ssd/file55` fails because source is not there, does it attempt to write anything in the destination at all ?

I am asking because I am worried it would wear off the destination SSD, that is why most of these files are kept in /ramdisk

Answer (score 2):

The only real way to answer this is to look through the source code. Implementations could vary.

In particular, I assume by `mv` you mean the one provided by [GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/).

I'm not confident that I understand all the nuances in their `mv` code, but I can note these facts:

- In `src/mv.c` there is a function `do_move(const char *source, const char *dest, const struct cp_options *x)` which is presumably the main driver for `mv`. That function invokes another function called `copy`.
- In `src/copy.c`, the `copy` function invoked by `do_move` is basically a wrapper to another function called `copy_internal`.
- At the top of the `copy_internal` function it attempts to `stat` the source file. If that fails, it bails out without doing anything.

Therefore, I think it is safe to answer:

Attempting to `mv` a non-existent file will not affect the destination until various checks have passed.

Comment: thank you, yes, the `--version` mentions `mv (GNU coreutils) 8.21`

Comment: @adrianTNT Cool. My answer is based on the code for coreutils 8.30.